# Any type of file is been update on my rules of allowed_types

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter and I want to upload an image.
Therefore I tried to limit the allowed file extensions using 'allowed_types'.

However I still accepts any file extension when I upload something.

This is a simple form.

```php
$configImagem['upload_path']   = './files/noticias/imagens';
$configImagem['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
$configImagem['file_name']     = 'noticia_'.date('y-m-d_h-i-s');

$this->upload->initialize($configImagem);
```

I expect an error when I upload a file with a extension not in allowed_types.

Comment: did you load the library?

Comment: yes, the library is load on autoload

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question. In your config.php did you load a language file other than English?

Comment: no, i didnt change the default. The array is empty

Comment: the problem is that allowed_types dont verify the file extentions. I check many examples and they do the same way as i, but on my project dont work

Comment: try `$config['language'] = 'english';` and check if you have this file: system/language/english/upload_lang.php

Comment: yes, i have it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194077/discussion-between-vickel-and-marcos-neto).

Comment: institute the traditional error checking that is in the documentation `if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) { echo $this->upload->display_errors(); }` and see what it is. codeigniter won't upload files that extensions/mime-type is not in the acceptable types array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some weird things happens when you use `initialize()` method from the upload library, that's why i stopped using this method and depended on reloading the library itself with the new configs array, i'm pretty sure this will work:

```
$configImagem['upload_path']   = './files/noticias/imagens';
$configImagem['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
$configImagem['file_name']     = 'noticia_'.date('y-m-d_h-i-s');

$this->load->library('upload', $configImagem);
```

Now these configs will override the default configs which accepts any mime type by default.